# tmux exits with [exited] 1;2c on macOS catalina

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, tmux

I recently upgraded to macOS Catalina and ever since my `tmux` seems to be broken. Whenever I run a `tmux` command or even just type `tmux` I get the error: `[exited] ^[[?1;2c`. I have reinstalled `tmux` multiple times with homebrew, I have restarted my computer, I have deleted everything from my `.tmux.conf` file, and I tried installing `reattach-to-user-namespace` just in case which seemed to be the problem for some other people but none of this has made any impact. I am using a `zsh` terminal and `tmux` used to work fine with it up until recently (no changes were made other than updating OS).

Comment: What is the default shell listed in your `.tmux.conf` file?

Comment: @DrZoo I set it to `zsh`

Comment: and yes I sourced the config after every change

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Leo-T I was able to resolve it by uninstalling, restarting, installing, etc. a couple of times -- not sure what exactly the problem was but I think it has something to do with not cleaning up the prior installations

Comment: This problem resolved for me after I exited all my tmux instances

Answer (score 16):

I encountered same problem for byobu.
I tried

```
pkill byobu..
```

not resolved...
Then I tried

```
pkill tmux
```

and it solved the problem for me...
The problem might've been due to tmux upgrade which was earlier this morning...
tmux 3.1a -> 3.1b

Also check [this link to another related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177257/tmux-server-does-not-start-with-zsh-returning-12c).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so since posting this question, my problem seems to have resolved itself. I have not changed anything with regards to my `tmux` installation directly so I am not 100% sure what exactly caused this issue or how it was resolved (apart from maybe restarting a couple more times?). I am posting this for future reference but if anyone is able to figure out why this problem was happening, I will gladly accept their answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the old `tmux` processes, and then reinstall again.

```
ps -ef |grep tmux
```

Comment: rifaqat already suggested `pkill tmux`, and the OP reported that the problem went away after reinstallation, so you don’t seem to be suggesting anything new here.

Answer (score 0):

`pkill tmux` works for me.

I'll explain what I encountered, not because of reinstallation or upgrade. I hope that can help someone here.

---

I tried to set an option at `.tmux.conf` on Macos system.

```bash
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh".
```

After that, I couldn't split a new pane. And despite exiting this session, I couldn't new a session and return the same message "[Exited]" as you.

`reattach-to-usernamespace` is not supported on my system, so this option can't run as I expected.

I guess if any operation causes Tmux not to be exited as usual, it will show this message. We must kill it manually.